# The following classes have no ground truth examples

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-recognition, object-detection-api

Ive trained ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model from zoo on dataset with ~25000 traffic signs pics 48x48 pixels like that one: [image: dataset example]

The training process looks fine (started from ~15.5 and decreased to 0.0135):[image: training]
but when i run eval.py with test dataset that contain ~7k pics :[image: eval start (warnings)]
and in the end i see error :The following classes have no ground truth examples  [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67]

[image: some more warnings]

Records generated from csv with that script:

```
    from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Jekoc\\Desktop\\TRAINING\\rus\\models-master\\research\\")
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Jekoc\\Desktop\\TRAINING\\rus\\models-master\\research\\object_detection\\utils")

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label != 0:
        return row_label
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_png = fid.read()
    encoded_png_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_png)
    image = Image.open(encoded_png_io)
    width, height = image.size
    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'png'#changed from jpg to png
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(0 / width)
        xmaxs.append(48 /width) # size is 48x48px so xmaxs=1
        ymins.append(0 /height)
        ymaxs.append(48 /height) # size is 48x48px so ymaxs=1
        classes_text.append(str(row['class']).encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))
    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_png),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

What i can do with that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is something wrong with your data, namely with the int class labels. I do not know why you use an object detection framework for the classification task, but to use it you need to prepare the label map that builds a correspondence between the class names and the integer IDs. See [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pascal_tf_record.py#L120).

That is in your code, by the way:

```
# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label != 0:
        return row_label
    else:
        None
```

So, you need to:

1. Create a label map for your dataset. See examples [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/data).
2. Create a label_dict from it: `label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(FLAGS.label_map_path)`
3. Use it to get the integer ID: `classes.append(label_map_dict[row['class']])`

Comment: i generate my records using csv file with structure |filename,class|
|000000.png,67| (for example) and all that classes are in my label map: item {
  id: 1
  name: '1.1' 
} that label map is used in model configuration file for training and eval. i use object detection api because model training is the first step of my app with traffic sign recognition via camera. By the way im not sure in that line 'classes.append(label_map dict[row['class']])' because neither of examples of label maps are have 'rows' and especially rows with name 'class'.